# Handling client/server communications over TCP - general question

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, tcp, network-programming

It's a little tricky to Google my question, because it's more of a question about the process rather than a strictly technical issue.

I'm setting up a basic TCP client/server system and I'm wondering how the back-and-forth communication should ideally work.  In my specific situation, the client will have to submit login credentials, and make specific requests from the server (the server interacts with a remote database).

Here is what I would THINK to do.. and I'm just looking from input from other devs.

```
SERVER: Wait for new connections
CLIENT: Connects to server
CLIENT: Once connected, send login credentials with an instruction code.
        i.e. $LOGIN$,username,password
SERVER: Check instruction code, if code = $LOGIN$, try to authenticate
SERVER: If authentication fails, send user message saying login failed
        i.e. $MSG$,101,Login Failed
CLIENT: If instruction code = $MSG$ and if message id = 101, display message and disconnect.
```

And another scenario.. let's say the client wants to request a log of what's happened on the server recently (the text of a console application window).

```
CLIENT: Send request message to server for recent log
        i.e. $REQ$,105
SERVER: If instruction = $REQ$ and request id = 105, get window text and send to client
        i.e. $DATA$,105,<data here>
CLIENT: If instruction = $DATA$ and data id = 105, parse data and display to user
```

The data being requested could be plain text, or a .net datatable translated into XML, etc.  It could be a variety of things.

Thoughts on this?  Tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this question could be re-worded to be more 'canonical' - of the form: "How to implement two-way communication over TCP in .NET?"

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend using [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106) over a secure (https) connection. It's ideal for exposing datasets over the network in a flexible and efficient manner, relying on proven ASP.NET authentication for security.

If you still want basic TCP/IP, consider the following:

- You'll need encrypted communications (SSL/TLS or similar), since you're passing authentication information.
- A common structure for messages is "type, length, data" (TLD). This enables some backwards compatibility, since the receiver may skip over message types it doesn't recognize.
- Remember that TCP/IP is not a messaging protocol but a streaming protocol, so you'll need [message framing](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/message-framing.html).
- You'll also need to include provisions for [detecting half-open connections](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html).
- Evaluate the level of protection you need to prevent SQL injection attacks; in general, a server receiving SQL as text is a bad idea.

Note that WCF Data Services (when used over HTTPS) handles all of the above for you.

Comment: Excellent reply, thank you.  I was unaware of WCF, but I will certainly look into it.